# Convert multiple rows into single column

Tags: sql, t-sql, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first, cursor

I have a database table, UserRewards that has 30+ million rows. In this row, there is a userID, and a rewardID per row (along with other fields).

There is a users table (has around 4 million unique users), that has the primary key userID, and other fields.
For performance reasons, I want to move the rewardID per user in userrewards into a concatenated field in users. (new nvarchar(4000) field called Rewards)
I need a script that can do this a fast as possible.

I have a cursor which joins up the rewards using the script below, but it only processes around 100 users per minute, which would take far too long to get though the around 4 million unique users I have.

```
 set @rewards = ( select REPLACE( (SELECT rewardsId AS [data()] from userrewards
 where UsersID = @users_Id and BatchId = @batchId
       FOR XML PATH('')  ), ' ', ',') )
```

Any suggestions to optimise this? I am about to try a while loop so see how that works, but any other ideas would be greatly received.

EDIT:

My site does the following:

We have around 4 million users who have been pre assigned 5-10 "awards". This relationship is in the userrewards table.

A user comes to the site, we identify them, and lookup in the database the rewards assigned to them.

Issue is, the site is very popular, so I am having a large number of people hitting the site at the same time requesting their data. The above will reduce my joins, but I understand this may not be the best solution. My database server goes upto 100% CPU usage within 10 seconds of me turing the site on, so most people's requests timeout (they are shown an error page), or they get results, but not in a satisfactory time.

Is anyone able to suggest a better solution to my issue?

Comment: ... really?  I can already tell you that using a delimited column (multi-value column) in SQL is **REALLY** heavily frowned upon.  'For performance' isn't a compelling reason (querying the column tends to be more trouble than it's worth) - often they end up in separate columns in analytic databases.  4mil rows is so-so, but peanuts on any dedicated system.  Also, cursors/loops are usually the wrong thing to do in SQL in general (which is probably the largest part of your performance problem).  What _actual_ problem are you trying to solve.  What other queries are 'slow'?

Comment: Queries are on their own fast, but I have got 5k-10k users hitting my server at the same time, requesting data from the userrewards table. (the one with 30 million rows). This joins to the users table, and filers on a unique identifier form the user. My updated code in one column has implemented better caching, and doesn't do any joins, and is a lot faster. I just need to get my current large dataset into the correct format, as quickly as I can. Right now, the SQL server is a dedicated box. I need to see about ugradding it.. Should I up RAM, CPU or Both? currently 8gb ram, 2.00 zeon CPU

Comment: In terms of the one column thing, whilst it maybe frowned upon, I have for efficient code that was faster than before.

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't want to stick this into the `User` table regardless.  If it turned out I did need to save aggregate results, I'd prefer to insert it into a 'temp' table, not the user one.  Potentially, I'd `PIVOT` the results into a new table, with a column-per-reward.  That's if the optimizer didn't provide better ways for me to cache things.  Is it not saving the access paths?  Do you have an actual performance issue yet?  Were indices not enough?

Comment: Sadly indices were not enough. Site was turned on, and within 10 seconds, my server hit 100% CPU usage. As A FYI, this is a .NET MVC 3 site, using entity framework code first

Comment: How are you querying it currently?  Are you sure that the database is the sole bottleneck?  If the individual users are causing the issue, eliminating one join this way _might_ not be that helpful; this _might_ be a time when more hardware would help.  For that number of options, you could potentially store them as bit flags in an int (dependent on required data).

Comment: Querying is done from MVC 3 site. Right now, I am sorting my data so I can create a clustered index on the lookup value, and will sorting out caching in code. Fingers crossed this will fix things for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several reasons why I think the approach you are attempting is a bad idea.  First, how are you going to maintain the comma delimited list in the users table?  It is possible that the rewards are loaded in batch, say at night, so this isn't really a problem now.  Even so, one day you might want to assign the rewards more frequently.

Second, what happens when you want to delete a reward or change the name of one of them?  Instead of updating one table, you need to update the information in two different places.

If you have 4 million users, with thousands of concurrent accesses, then small inconsistencies due to timing will be noticeable and may generate user complaints.  A call from the CEO on why complaints are increasing is probably not something you want to deal with.

An alternative is to build an index on UserRewards(UserId, BatchId, RewardsId).  Presumably, each field is few bytes, so 30 million records should easily fit into 8 Gbytes of memory (be sure that SQL Server is allocated almost all the memory!).  The query that you want can be satisfied strictly  by this index, without having to bring the UserRewards table into memory.  So, only the index needs to be cached.  And, it will be optimized for this query.

One thing that might be slowing everything down is the frequency of assigning rewards.  If these are being assigned at even 10% of the read rate, you could have the inserts/updates blocking the reads.  You want to do the queries with READ_NOLOCK, to avoid this problem.  You also want to be sure that locking is occurring at the record or page level, to avoid conflicts with the reads.

Comment: Rewards as assigned monthly, and don't change during the month. Site is "closed" during reward reload. I already have an index on the table, but I am joining to other tables to get actual data. However, I could cache the "reward data" on the web server, as again, this won't change during the month. AS for index, should I include the primary key on the userrewads table, or just the foreign keys (rewardsIDm usersID, and batchID)

Comment: I am also using uniqueidentifiers as my keys.. Is this going to cause me problems maybe? I think I'll see if I can get the server another 8GB of ram

Answer (score 0):

Maybe too late, but using uniqueidentifiers as keys will not only quadruple your storage space (compared to using ints as keys), but slow your queries by orders of magnitude. AVOID!!!